# Bus Seating Map

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Full-featured Seating Chart Plugin With jQuery - Seat Charts](https://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Full-featured-Seating-Chart-Plugin-With-jQuery-Seat-Charts.html)

Currently the checkout button in this code is working when someone try to click it without selecting any of the seats displayed in the chart. Therefore, I want to  restrict it to fade the checkout button until someone is selecting a seat and show after selecting a seat.

Comment: that's an interesting plugin - did **you** write it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we expect you to show us the code that you have tried writing yourself to solve a problem, along with any error that is occurring and what you tried to do to fix it. Then we can help you debug your program so that it works. So - please edit your question and add the actual, *relevant* code snippets for us to see :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anu,

have a look at this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery Seat Charts Plugin Demo</title>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.seat-charts.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleCheckoutButtonState()
{
 var isSeatSelected= $("#seat-map [aria-checked='true'").length>0;
 if(isSeatSelected)
   $("#btnCheckout").removeAttr("disabled");
 else
   $("#btnCheckout").attr("disabled",true);
}
</script>
<style>
body {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color:#fafafa;
}
a {
 color: #b71a4c;
}
.front-indicator {
 width: 145px;
 margin: 5px 32px 15px 32px;
 background-color: #f6f6f6; 
 color: #adadad;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 3px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
  margin-top:150px;
}
.container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 500px;
 text-align: left;
}
.booking-details {
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: 35px;
 font-size: 12px;
 position: relative;
 height: 401px;
}
.booking-details h2 {
 margin: 25px 0 20px 0;
 font-size: 17px;
}
.booking-details h3 {
 margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
 font-size: 14px;
}
div.seatCharts-cell {
 color: #182C4E;
 height: 25px;
 width: 25px;
 line-height: 25px;
 
}
div.seatCharts-seat {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 cursor: pointer; 
}
div.seatCharts-row {
 height: 35px;
}
div.seatCharts-seat.available {
 background-color: #B9DEA0;

}
div.seatCharts-seat.available.first-class {
/*  background: url(vip.png); */
 background-color: #3a78c3;
}
div.seatCharts-seat.focused {
 background-color: #76B474;
}
div.seatCharts-seat.selected {
 background-color: #E6CAC4;
}
div.seatCharts-seat.unavailable {
 background-color: #472B34;
}
div.seatCharts-container {
 border-right: 1px dotted #adadad;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 20px;
 float: left;
}
div.seatCharts-legend {
 padding-left: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 16px;
}
ul.seatCharts-legendList {
 padding-left: 0px;
}
span.seatCharts-legendDescription {
 margin-left: 5px;
 line-height: 30px;
}
.checkout-button {
 display: block;
 margin: 10px 0;
 font-size: 14px;
}
#selected-seats {
 max-height: 90px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: none;
 width: 170px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body><div id="jquery-script-menu">
<div class="jquery-script-center">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Full-featured-Seating-Chart-Plugin-With-jQuery-Seat-Charts.html">Download This Plugin</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/">Back To jQueryScript.Net</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="jquery-script-ads"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2783044520727903";
/* jQuery_demo */
google_ad_slot = "2780937993";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></div>
<div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
  <h1>jQuery Seat Charts Plugin Demo</h1>
    <div id="seat-map" onclick="toggleCheckoutButtonState()">
      <div class="front-indicator">Front</div>
    </div>
    <div class="booking-details">
      <h2>Booking Details</h2>
      <h3> Selected Seats (<span id="counter">0</span>):</h3>
      <ul id="selected-seats">
      </ul>
      Total: <b>$<span id="total">0</span></b>
      <button id="btnCheckout" disabled="true" class="checkout-button">Checkout &raquo;</button>
      <div id="legend"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.seat-charts.js"></script> 
<script>
   var firstSeatLabel = 1;
  
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var $cart = $('#selected-seats'),
     $counter = $('#counter'),
     $total = $('#total'),
     sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
     map: [
      'ff_ff',
      'ff_ff',
      'ee_ee',
      'ee_ee',
      'ee___',
      'ee_ee',
      'ee_ee',
      'ee_ee',
      'eeeee',
     ],
     seats: {
      f: {
       price   : 100,
       classes : 'first-class', //your custom CSS class
       category: 'First Class'
      },
      e: {
       price   : 40,
       classes : 'economy-class', //your custom CSS class
       category: 'Economy Class'
      }     
     
     },
     naming : {
      top : false,
      getLabel : function (character, row, column) {
       return firstSeatLabel++;
      },
     },
     legend : {
      node : $('#legend'),
         items : [
       [ 'f', 'available',   'First Class' ],
       [ 'e', 'available',   'Economy Class'],
       [ 'f', 'unavailable', 'Already Booked']
         ]     
     },
     click: function () {
      if (this.status() == 'available') {
       //let's create a new <li> which we'll add to the cart items
       $('<li>'+this.data().category+' Seat # '+this.settings.label+': <b>$'+this.data().price+'</b> <a href="#" class="cancel-cart-item">[cancel]</a></li>')
        .attr('id', 'cart-item-'+this.settings.id)
        .data('seatId', this.settings.id)
        .appendTo($cart);
       
       /*
        * Lets update the counter and total
        *
        * .find function will not find the current seat, because it will change its stauts only after return
        * 'selected'. This is why we have to add 1 to the length and the current seat price to the total.
        */
       $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length+1);
       $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)+this.data().price);
       
       return 'selected';
      } else if (this.status() == 'selected') {
       //update the counter
       $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length-1);
       //and total
       $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)-this.data().price);
      
       //remove the item from our cart
       $('#cart-item-'+this.settings.id).remove();
      
       //seat has been vacated
       return 'available';
      } else if (this.status() == 'unavailable') {
       //seat has been already booked
       return 'unavailable';
      } else {
       return this.style();
      }
     }
    });

    //this will handle "[cancel]" link clicks
    $('#selected-seats').on('click', '.cancel-cart-item', function () {
     //let's just trigger Click event on the appropriate seat, so we don't have to repeat the logic here
     sc.get($(this).parents('li:first').data('seatId')).click();
    });

    //let's pretend some seats have already been booked
    sc.get(['1_2', '4_1', '7_1', '7_2']).status('unavailable');
  
  });

  function recalculateTotal(sc) {
   var total = 0;
  
   //basically find every selected seat and sum its price
   sc.find('selected').each(function () {
    total += this.data().price;
   });
   
   return total;
  }
  
  </script><script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which don't supply code or markup here as required. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer it was really helpful